# Make a REST service that uses another SOAP service C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, web-services, soap

I have made a simple **REST** service (**WCF**) that will be using another **SOAP** service.

My **REST** service works fine, but when I add the **SOAP** service (**Added as a Service Reference**), it adds data to the **Web.config** file.

One thing I want to highlight is that I do not want to expose the **SOAP** service, I'll be just consuming it.

But when I try to invoke an operation, I get this error:

> The endpoint at *www.myaddress.com* does not have a Binding with the
>   None MessageVersion. 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior'
>   is only intended for use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.

Looking on the internet, people have issues with the config file, but they're exposing two services. I am just exposing one service, and consuming the other. For now, the **REST** service I am consuming through **localhost**, and the **SOAP** service uses **SAML ADFS authentication**

This is how my config file look, can someone please suggest a fix?

```xml
    <configuration>

      <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_mySOAPService">
              <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                <message>
                  <issuer address="issuer.address"/>
                  <issuerMetadata address="issuer.metadata.address" />
                  <tokenRequestParameters>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                  </tokenRequestParameters>
                </message>
              </security>
            </binding>
          </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
          <ws2007HttpBinding>
            <binding name="binding.address">
              <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false" />
              </security>
            </binding>
          </ws2007HttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="endpoint.address"
            binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_mySOAPService"
            contract="ServiceReference1.mySOAPService" name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_mySOAPService" />
        </client>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>    
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <!--
            To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
            Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
          -->
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
      </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's exactly how it will work by default!

But you can override those settings pretty easily.

```
        var soapService = new SoapClass.SoapService(
            new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport), //Pick the right mode here
            new EndpointAddress(mySoapUrl));
```

My assumption being you have multiple projects, and the Soap is being added to the wrong config.

The other choice, would be to move the correct config settings to the correct config.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Austin, but no, I have them both in the same project. In that project I need to consume the SOAP service while I expose the REST service.

Comment: The code I gave is for connecting (consuming) a SOAP service. Can you connect / instantiate the soap service with the approach I gave?

Comment: Yes, it works. But when I do soapService.operation(), then I get that exception. I created a separate project, and can consume the SOAP web service there with no problem.